# Android: зачёркнутый текст в ListView

Tags: android, java

Как правильно при нажатии на пункт в listview делать текст в нём зачёркнутым?

Пробовал нечто такое, но это не работает:

```
  viewer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                TextView through_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
                through_text.setPaintFlags(through_text.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            }
        });
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно писать свой адаптер, в котором хранить индексы перечеркнутых элементов и метод который будет их задавать.
При клике вызывается этот метод и перерисовывается listview